# join tibbles by unordered list

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have two tibbles: `a` and `b`.

```
a <- tibble("unordered_characters" = list( c("A","B"), c("X","Y") ) ,
            "v" = c("G", "F"))
b <- tibble("unordered_characters" = list( c("B","A"), c("Y","X")),
            "x" = c("M", "d"))
```

I want to join `b` on `a` using their common variable, which is a list. But I want the list to be unordered, so that `c("A","B")` should be the same as `c("B","A")`.
In other words, `setequal(c("A","B"),c("B","A"))` returns `TRUE`. This would to create the following table:

```
unordered_characters v x
------------------------
c("A","B")            G M 
c("X","Y")           F d
```

But `a %>% left_join(b)` results in the following:

```
unordered_characters v x
------------------------
c("A","B")            G NA 
c("X","Y")           F NA
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `map` to loop over the `list` and `sort` before doing the join

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
a %>% 
  mutate(unordered_characters = map(unordered_characters, sort)) %>% 
  left_join(b %>% 
       mutate(unordered_characters = map(unordered_characters, sort)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  unordered_characters v     x    
#  <list>               <chr> <chr>
#1 <chr [2]>            G     M    
#2 <chr [2]>            F     d
```